# Migrating Data From Amazon Redshift into Aurora DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, etl, amazon-aurora

There are tons of examples to migrate data from Aurora DB to Redshift, but I couldn't find any example or documentation for migrating data from Redshift to Aurora DB. Any suggestion/example/doc for migrating data from Redshift into Aurora DB in an efficient way?

Comment: can you explain more about your data flows / reasoning?

Comment: https://github.com/aws-samples/data-pipeline-samples/tree/master/samples/RedshiftToRDS

Comment: Hi our customer asked us a data entry web app using Aurora as database. They want  to load some data from Redshift. Then users can change them for some reports and they don't have to turn back to Redshift.

Comment: Another requirement is that data import, Redshift to Aurora, should be execute every night

Comment: You could use Aurora Postgres and set up a external view, using the info here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/join-amazon-redshift-and-amazon-rds-postgresql-with-dblink/ - would that work for you?

Comment: I found the same solution surfing on internet. i will ask to customer if it's possible to set up a similar environment. No other options?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by unloading[1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html) the data into S3 directly from RedShift and then loading it into Aurora[2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.LoadFromS3.html)&[3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_PostgreSQL.S3Import.html).

[Redshift UNLOAD Official Docs.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html)

[Aurora MySQL LOAD FROM S3 Offical Docs.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.LoadFromS3.html)

[Aurora PostgreSQL LOAD FROM S3 Official Docs.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_PostgreSQL.S3Import.html)

Note that the LOAD on Aurora does not support .parquet or other colunar files, so your best shot is to unload it as .csv. Depending on the size of your tables, you might consider doing it in batches or in periods of reduced workload.

By the moment I'm writting this answer you **can't** use Redshift as a source for DMS, otherwise this would be the prefered way.